# Using variables in inline CSS to create PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, wicked-pdf

I'm using Wicked PDF to generate PDF's. So I have a view `contract.pdf.haml` to create the view and I want to use dynamic padding based on some business logic (not relevant). So in the view I created 2 variables (later these will come from the controller) for `padding-top` and `padding-left`:

```
- if 1>0
  - padding_top = "970px"
  - padding_left = "380px"
- else
  - padding_top = "50px"
  - padding_left = "100px"
```

And then I am using these variables in the inline CSS:

```
:css
  .signature-box {
    padding-top: padding_top;
    padding-left: padding_left;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    width: 50%;
  }
```

But when the PDF is generated, I see the padding is not applied. What is wrong here?